# Is it possible to disable one listItem from radioButton list in asp.net 

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to **disable one listItem** from **RadioButtonList** depend on condition like if `querystring contain true` then it will display both the ListItem or else it disabled 2nd listItem ie(External). So user can't access 2nd list item

I have url like

`abc.com/Account.aspx?type=true`

`abc.com/Account.aspx?type=false`

Code On page Account.aspx

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdodomiantype" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onclick="setTextbox()">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" >Default</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" >External</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I think the reason you have been downvoted is that you start your "question" with *My requirement is* ... this is a Q and A site - not a rent a developer site ... please rephrase it so that it reads like a question and shows effort on your part to resolve your issue

Comment: @ManseUK: Thank you and i apologies for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how i solved with the help of HariHaran

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string planType=Request.QueryString["type"];
   if (planType == "False")
    {
      rdodomiantype.Items.Remove(rdodomiantype.Items.FindByValue("1"));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

I didn't want to remove the item from a list, I wanted to disable it like the original poster asked.  As such, here's the code I was able to use (EDIT - converted to C# and checking for querystring param based on original post:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["type"]) && Request.QueryString["type"].ToUpper() == "TRUE")
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in rdoList.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Text == "External")
                    {
                        item.Enabled = false;
                        item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#999;");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it necessary to disable one list item?
My suggestion is according to the query string value you can bind the dropdown. ie if the query string value is true then you van bind the dropdown with both list item values;

or if the query string value is false you can bind the dropdown with first list item only.

Comment: yes i agree with you but heres am having a problem that i cant change the design and controls the existing design have radiobuttonlist, so is their any posibilities to do this ?

Comment: @satindersingh: Don't add the ListItems in the aspx page. You can add it from the code behind.

Comment: @satinder Just a suggestion, why not you dont add the specific item to list based on the querystrging, instead of adding and disabling?

Comment: @Satinder: I believe you will be adding the list item from code behind from run time. If my understanding is correct, you can check the query string for "true" or "false", based on that you can add or remove the list item which is not needed.  Please refer the existing post  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729652/asp-net-show-hide-radio-button-list-items-programmatically)

Comment: Sample code to remove a list item from radio button  'code' RadioButtonList1.Items.Remove(RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue("Hardware"))

Comment: @HariHaran: thank you, depend on querysting and adding listitem ie(if true i add two list item  else one)::: also thanks for that useful link